# About the definition of completion of a metric space $R$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

The definition of **completion** of a metric space $R$ is the following:

> Definition 1:
> Given a metric space $R$ with closure $[R]$, a complete metric space $R^*$ is called a **completion** of $R$ if $R\subset R^*$ and $[R]=R^*$, i.e., if $R$ is a subset of $R^*$ everywhere dense in $R^*$.

Why is the following definition of mine bad?

> My definition:
> Given a metric space $R$, a complete metric space $R^*$ is called a **completion** of $R$ if $R\subset R^*$.

---

jjagmath, thank you very much for your comment.

Is the following definition equivalent to the definition 1?

> My definition 2:
> Given a metric space $R$, a complete metric space $R^*$ is called a **completion** of $R$ if $R^*$ is the smallest complete metric space which includes $R$.

Comment: Do you really want to say, for example, that $[0,1]$, $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ are completions of the space $(0,1)$?

Comment: @saulspatz: Not $\Bbb R^2$, save by abuse of notation: $(0,1)\nsubseteq\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Is the completion of a metric space $R$ the smallest complete metric space which includes $R$?

Comment: Imagine you are interested in a space, but it's not complete, so you add some points to make it complete. And a disjoint circle. Does it sound natural to add the circle? May be your original space was a space of functions... It's will be odd that your new space is the union of a set of functions and a set of points of $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: What does “smallest” mean? Say you have $[0,1)$ with the usual metric. I can complete it by taking $[0,1)\cup\{*\}$, and a suitable definition of the metric; or by taking $[0,1)\cup\{\#\}$; or $[0,1)\cup\{3\}$ (with a suitable metric), or $[0,1]$. Which one is “smallest”?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you very much. If we define $\rho(x,y)=|x-y|$ for $x,y\in [0,1)$ and $\rho(x,3)=|x-1|$ for $x\in [0,1)$ and $\rho(3,3)=0$, then $[0,1)\cup\{3\}$ is a complete metric space which includes $[0,1)$. And $[0,1]$ is not a subset of $[0,1)\cup\{3\}$ and $[0,1)\cup\{3\}$ is not a subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @jjagmath Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: That’s the point; that there may be no way to compare two complete spaces that contain your original one in order to decide which one is “smaller”, so talking in the abstract about “smallest” doesn’t actually mean anything unless you explain how you compare metric spaces to decide which one is smaller, and you prove that there is a “smallest” one.

Comment: The phrase "Given a metric space $R$ with closure $[R]$" does not make sense on its own. Using $[R]$ only makes sense if we are given an ambient $R^* \supset R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take as our starting metric space $[0,1)$. Obviously the "right" completion is $[0,1]$, that is:

- take the original space;
- add a new point to it, namely $1$;
- extend the metric to set $d(a,1)=1-a$ for each $a\in [0,1)$.

However, this isn't the only thing we could do. For example, we could also look at the metric space whose underlying set is $[0,1)\cup\{17\}$ with distance function $f$ given by $f(x,y)=\vert x-y\vert$ if $x,y\in [0,1)$, $f(17,17)=0$, and for $a\in [0,1)$ we set $f(a,17)=f(17,a)=1-a$.

This sort of issue indicates why "definitions" like "the smallest complete metric space containing $R$" are going to be problematic: they require us to compare objects which don't, on the face of it, admit any sort of meaningful comparison. That said, there are a couple ways to make your proposed definition precise, which I'll phrase as theorems (using the standard definition of "completion"):

- Suppose $R\subseteq R^*$ are metric spaces with $R^*$ complete. Then $R^*$ is a completion of $R$ iff *no proper subspace of $R^*$ containing $R$* is complete. (So completions are "internally minimal.")
- Suppose $R\subseteq R^*$ are metric spaces with $R^*$ complete. Then $R^*$ is a completion of $R$ iff for every complete metric space $S$ with $R\subseteq S$ there is a unique isometric embedding of $R^*$ into $S$ which is the identity on $R$. (So completions are "minimal with respect to comparisons via isometries.")

The second notion isn't as snappy, but it's actually getting at a deeper idea than the first (that of figuring out how to compare very disparate objects by looking for maps between them, especially *unique* maps, satisfying certain nice properties).

Comment: Noah Schweber, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

*The charm of universal problems.-*
Too long for a comment, I would like to highlight the point of view of universal problems which is evoked as second point in the end of Noah's answer.
Indeed, completions of a metric space are not unique (but they are isomorphic) and, oftentimes, in the constructions of the "working mathematician", the original space $R$ does not come naturally as a subspace of the completed one $R^*$. As example, one can cite the celebrated completion $\mathbb{R}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ which can come from

- Limits of Cauchy sequences

  Order i.e. Dedekind cuts, see [1]

  Classes of functions, see Eudoxus real numbers [2]

As regards completions, the following definition, IMHO, is the best.

**Definition.-** Let $(R,d)$  be a metric space. A completion of $R$ is a pair $(u,R^*)$, where

- $(R^*,d^*)$ is a complete metric space

  $u:\ R\to R^*$ is uniformly continuous

Such that, for all  $w:\ R\to T$ uniformly continuous 
(where $(T,d_T)$ is a complete metric space), it exists a unique $v:\ R^*\to T$, uniformly continuous, with $w=v\circ u$.

As for every such scheme (algebraic closure, tensor products, enveloping algebras etc.), one shows  easily that all completions are isomorphic (i.e. “completion” is unique “ up to isomorphism”).

At the end of the day, if one prefers inclusion maps rather than embeddings, one can even - at the cost of a bit of surgery - tailor solutions $(u,R^*)$ where $u$ is an inclusion map.

[1] [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut)
[2] [Eudoxus real numbers](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eudoxus+real+number)